# Leave of absense from work

Tags: quitting, sickness

I have had a medical condition for almost year. It has gotten worse with me having seizures. My company put me on a leave of absence and says I cannot go back till I am safe to work. The leave of absence is for 30 days. My condition will take a lot longer than that to even start feeling better. Can I get and financial help? I have no vacation time or personal time so I am pennyless. any ideas?

Comment: Do you have [Disability Insurance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disability_insurance)? That would be applicable here.

Comment: Please  specify the country you live in.

Answer (score 2):

First check with your employer'd HR to see if you have short-term and long-term disability insurance. Also ask if they can advance you leave or ask other employees if they would be willing to share some of their leave with you (some places allow leave sharing for ill employees.)

If those don't work out, then you are going to need to move it with a family member or friend. Give up your phone and your cable and any other discretionary expenses. See about putting credit card payments on hold until you are better. (Note if you do that, you will not be able to actually use the credit cards, but if you can't make the payment then you shouldn't be going further in debt.) You can also set up a GoFundMe page and see if people are willing to help you out. Also talk to your local government offices about welfare (or whatever it is called in your country) (and possibly unemployment) and there may be a way to apply for a disability although that usually takes longer than you have. Some churches have charity as well.